# get woocommerce product price in php

Tags: php, woocommerce, product

I'm trying to get woocommerce product price and assigning it's value to an image attribute. But it shows like "1595 null" in need to like "$1595" or "1595$"
Here is the code

```
<?php
    $price_html = $product->get_price();
    echo '<a href="#" data_price="'.$price_html.'">';
?>
```

Comment: are your *really* sure that null is coming from get_price? `var_dump($product->get_price());`

Comment: My guess is you are not getting currency sign .. Right ?
If this is the case, then you need to add [get_woocommerce_currency_symbol](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/function-get_woocommerce_currency_symbol.html) So your code will be `echo '<a href="#" data_price="'.get_woocommerce_currency_symbol().''.$price_html.'">';`

Comment: I checked, when I do "echo $price_html; it shows 1595" But in <a tag it shows with null.